# What does the "Incremental Dex" option in Android Studio do?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, when you select a module in Project Structure window, under Properties tab there is an option to set "Incremental Dex" to true or false. What exactly does it do, and when should it be used?

Answer (score 22):

It is similar to incremental build, which re-builds its outputs by only building if an input file has been modified. It is useful to reduce the build time.

"only the dex files of modified modules are recomputed and repackaged into the APK file"
taken from https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html