# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/inject/Module

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, dex

I am trying to solve this exception. I have 2 android projects in intellij.
Library and sample.

Library's deps are the following:

```
   compile('com.inepex.simpleclient:SimpleClientImpl:0.9.4') {
        exclude module: 'guice-assistedinject'
        exclude module: 'guice'
        exclude module: 'ormlite-core'
    }
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1@jar'
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0:no_aop'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1@jar'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.45'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
```

sample app deps:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.1.0'
compile project(':library')
```

gradle dependencies output for sample:

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0                                   
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
+--- com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
\--- project :library               
     +--- com.inepex.simpleclient:SimpleClientImpl:0.9.4
     |    +--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:4.45
     |    +--- io.netty:netty:3.5.7.Final
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:17.0
     +--- org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1
     +--- com.google.inject:guice:3.0
     |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
     |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
     |    \--- org.sonatype.sisu.inject:cglib:2.2.1-v20090111
     |         \--- asm:asm:3.1     
     +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.0
     |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
     |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.0
     +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1
     +--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.45
     |    \--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.45
     +--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
     \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+ -> 2.2.4
```

Problem is that I can't find com.google.inject.Module more then once and the exception tells it is multiple defined. It is in guice.3.0-no_aop.jar.

Thanks in advance

Balint

Comment: Try to remove this : compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0' from sample app deps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Failing Test runs with Multi Dex configuration

If your project uses multi dex configuration check the dex options in the gradle config. It should NOT contain `incremental true`.

I had a project failing to execute instrumentation tests from Android Studio with this error after each code change. I had to clean the project before each run until I removed this property.

*(this property defaults to false so if it's not there you're fine)*

```
dexOptions {
        incremental false
        javaMaxHeapSize '4g'
    }
```

For more details on what this dex option does check [What does the "Incremental Dex" option in Android Studio do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779552/what-does-the-incremental-dex-option-in-android-studio-do)

## About Finding Duplicate dependencies

With gradle you can create a dependency tree. This tree will mark obvious duplicates with an asterix at the end. Example:

```
./gradlew dependencies Application:dependencies
```

Example output (from the Instrumentation sample project, incomplete though)

```
_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2
_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2
_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2
_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2
     \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.2
androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.1.201405082137
androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.1.201405082137
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.1.201405082137
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.1.201405082137
     |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.1.201405082137 (*)
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.1.201405082137
```

Note how the org.jacoco.core dependency is listed here twice and marked with the (*).