# Should I change all annotationProcessor to kapt in Kotlin project

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room, android-glide

I noticed that I have to use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor` to make `Dagger 2` work properly in my Kotlin project. Do I have to do the same to all the libraries (specifically `Glide` and `Room`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is recommended to do so. The documentation stated:

> If you previously used the Android support for annotation processors, replace usages of the `annotationProcessor` configuration with `kapt`. If your project contains Java classes, `kapt` will also take care of them.

[Read more on Using kapt](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html)