# Android Dagger2 error: package android.app does not exist

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to configure Dagger2 to be able to inject Appliaction instance, but while build I'm getting weird error:

```
DaggerAppComponent.java:3: error: package android.app does not exist
import android.app.Application;
                  ^
```

Here's my code:

**Gradle Dagger2 dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.27'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27'
    ...
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [HttpModule::class, AuthModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(activity: BootstrapActivity)

    fun inject(activity: LoginActivity)
}
```

**MyApplication**

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    private lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
    }

    fun getAppComponent() = appComponent
}
```

**BootstrapActivity (NoDisplay)**

```
class BootstrapActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var auth: Auth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        (applicationContext as MyApplication).getAppComponent()
            .inject(this)

        //auth.fetchCurrentUser()

        val intent: Intent = if (auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        } else {
            Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        startActivity(intent)

        finish()
    }
}
```

How it's possible that android.app package does not exists? Please help me, I'm fighting 2 days with it :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use your own application class when you're using a custom app class instead of the default android one. So in order to do that change your app component builder to:

```
@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(app: MyApplication): Builder

    fun build(): AppComponent
}
```

Also don't forget to include the necessary dependencies in your **build.gradle**:

```
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.28'
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.28' // you're using the support libraries
```

And the annotation processor if you wish to use the android-specific annotations (which I recommend you to do):

```
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.28'
```

Comment: I tried this before. I added again these dependencies and changed type to `MyApplication` in component Builder, but this gives me new error during `Component.application(this)`:

`DaggerAppComponent.java:85: error: cannot access Application
      this.application = Preconditions.checkNotNull(app);
                                      ^
  class file for android.app.Application not found`

Comment: Have you added `apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"` to your **build.gradle** to use the kapt plugin?

Comment: Yes, it's present

Comment: Then according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58926463/4399414) answer try `annotationProcessor` instead of `kapt` and check if it solves the problem.

Comment: I posted an own answer. I had JVM version set to 10, downgrading to JVM 8 fixed this issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Probably I finally solved this issue. I had JVM version 10 in Gradle, changing it to 1.8 solved my issue